# How to use OR operator in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

I have a huge list of senders who I would like to filter in Gmail. If you can help me figure this out, I can finally get over this headache.

I've tried these queries.

1. `from:(David Kadavy OR Lloyed from Speakeasy OR Traction Conf)`

*No results*

2. `from:David Kadavy OR from:Lloyed from Speakeasy OR from:Traction Conf`

*No results*

3. `from:david kadavy || from:lloyed from speakeasy || from:traction conf`

*Only searches for david kadavy*

I've tried each search individually and they do return many results, so it's not that there are actually no results to show.

I have read the Gmail documentation, and it doesn't help me. https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example in the Google docs is of the form:

```
from:amy OR from:david
```

So, I would certainly go with your 2nd version. However, I think it might be getting confused by the spaces (ordinarily a *delimiter*) so it might be searching for something like: *(parentheses and `AND` added for clarity)*

```
from:David AND (Kadavy OR from:Lloyed) AND from AND (Speakeasy OR from:Traction) AND Conf
```

Try quoting the search phrase:

```
from:"David Kadavy" OR from:"Lloyed from Speakeasy" OR from:"Traction Conf"
```

or even,

```
"from:David Kadavy" OR "from:Lloyed from Speakeasy" OR "from:Traction Conf"
```

Both quoted search phrases seem to work for me, although the former matches Google's example: `subject:"dinner and a movie"` so would be the preferred style.

Comment: You're right, adding quotes fixes the problem. Thanks for the thorough explanation.